# Is there any way to install an "on edit trigger" in another google docs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the function I want to be triggered when On edit (Spreadsheet 1)

```
function sendData() 
{
    var value1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("third spreadsheet ID").getSheetByName("***").getRange("B2").setValue(value1);
}
```

From another spreadsheet (2) I wrote down:

```
function TriggerOn()
{ // create trigger
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("first Spreadsheet ID");
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("senData").forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet).onEdit().create();
}
```

But it doesn't work because forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet) only works on the same spreadsheet...

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_triggerbuilder), the argument for .forSpreadsheet() is the ID of the spreadsheet, not the spreadsheet itself.

try this instead :

```
function TriggerOn() { // create trigger
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("senData").forSpreadsheet("first Spreadsheet ID").onEdit().create();
    }
```

Comment: While it is possible to add an onEdit trigger for another spreadsheet, the trigger will always belong to the script that created it, and can only run functions within the script that created it.

Comment: downvote because there are two forSpreadsheet() methods,one of which does actually take a spreadsheet as its argument